# Is this hadith about giving a pair of shoes as mahr authentic?

Tags: hadith, authenticity, mehr

Is this hadith authentic giving a pair of shoes as mahr?

***A woman from Banu Fazhar was married with a pair of shoes being accepted as Mahr. Rasulullah (s) asked the woman: ‘Are you happy to give your possessions and soul in exchange for a pair of shoes?’ She replied: ‘Yes’. Rasulullah (s) then deemed this Nikah valid”.***

Sunan Tirmidhi Volume 1 page 152

Comment: i didn't find this would you give me a link ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This hadith has been quoted in Jami' [at-Tirmidhi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/11/34) and sunan [ibn Majah](http://sunnah.com/urn/1319630) other scholars like al-Bayhaqi have also quoted it.

At-Tirmidhi himself qualified it as hassan sahih and added that the scholars have different opinions about (amount of) the dowry while a-Shafi'i, Sufyan at-Thawri, Ishaaq (ibn Rahawayh) and Ahmad accept whatever the future spouses have agreed about, others have defined a minimum amount. At-Tirmidhi quoted other sources for similar statements (agreement about dowry).

Scholars on the whole consider this hadith as da'if because of 'Assim ibn 'Obayd Allah عَاصِمِ بْنِ عُبَيْدِ اللَّهِ. Ibn al-Jawzy quoted: Yahya ibn Ma'ayn who qualified him as weak and he considered him as somebody one couldn't rely on or use as a plead. Ibn Hebban even said his mistakes are grave even if this two sandals or shoes may have the worth of ten! Mulla Ali al-Qarri however made a commentary on this hadith in his [mirqat al-Mafatih sharh meshkaat al-Masabeeh](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=79&ID=6389) quoting this qualification. He also said that this woman had the opportunity to ask for more mahr but rejected and with her agreement this nikah became valid and pointed at the fact that mahr could also be what one memorizes of the Quran according ahadith like [this hadith](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/66/51) in sahih al-Bukhari.